# Can I change Price Granularity in prebid

Tags: prebid.js, prebid

Can I change price granularity in prebid header auction as per our need ? Prebid has the following price granularity- Low, Medium, High, Dense, Custom. I want to know if I set my DFP line items in a way where I will have a flexibility to use Price Granularity according to my preferences so that when required I can use low and when required medium or high. But I don't want to make changes to our DFP line items for that every time.

Can this be achieved ?

I've created DFP line items already in a increments of $0.05 like 0.05, 0.10, 0.15, 0.20, 0.25, 0.30 .... so on.

I want to understand for example if I set the line items at 0.05 increments capped at $20.00 then let's say if price granularity is set "low" then the increments will happen at 0.05 while in "medium" may be 0.10 increments. While I don't want to change DFP line item values every time I wish to change price granularity.

Also, please suggest, if we get $20 and above CPM, then how will we get it because prebid wil automatically round off and reduce the highest cpm to $20 bid.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple price granularities if you wish, as long as your line items have price buckets to match *at the most granular level*. For example, if you are using "medium" granularity and setup line items at $0.10 increments, switching to a "high" granularity ($0.01) would cause you to lose bids at those bids that didn't land exactly on a $0.10 increment (i.e. $1.17, $1.23 etc). However, switching to a lower granularity (ie "low") would be fine.

Related links:

http://prebid.org/adops/before-you-start.html#decide-on-price-bucket-granularity

http://prebid.org/dev-docs/common-issues.html#price-granularity-mismatch

http://prebid.org/dev-docs/publisher-api-reference.html#setConfig-Price-Granularity